# Problem while sending message through sockets

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I think it is really strange problem because I don't even know where to start when repairing it.
My problem is my client don't receive message send from server.
I know I provided very little amount of code but I think other code really does not matter in this problem. If you want me to provide more code comment and I will send it to you.

Server code

```
         String s = "";

         for(String a : Main.users.keySet()) {
                    
                    s = s + a + " ";
                    
                }

         System.out.println("Sendind message: " + "SERVER USERS " + s);
                
                output.writeBytes("SERVER USERS " + s);
                output.flush();         
                
                System.out.println("User message sent");
```

Main.users.keySet() returns Set of strings.

Server console

```
              SERVER USERS test
              User message sent
```

Client code

```
                System.out.println("TEST 1");

        while(true){

            try {

                     reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                    line = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println("TEST 2");
```

Client console

```
               I/System.out: TEST 1
```

Comment: 'Client code' is not printing what it reads… It could be blocked on that `readLine`, but you don't print it. If it *is* blocked then there's a logical error maybe

Comment: But I can't print it because it is null, that System.out.println("TEST 2");  is not executed because reader.readLine does not get any message.

Comment: See my second sentence^^. We can't know why from what you posted

Comment: Do you want me to post more client code? I can do it If you want

Comment: @g00se also I am preety new to java, what do you mean by logical error?

Comment: `Main.users.keySet())` We dont know what that returns.  So we dont know what the server sends. Please post code in such a way that we know.

Comment: Further: if the receiver tries to read a line... then what should te server have sent? Please tell.

Comment: You still have the same code. And also you did not react on readLine comment.

Comment: @blackapps Now I changed code and server code is 

          System.out.println("Sending message: " + "SERVER USERS " + s);
     
     output.writeBytes("SERVER USERS " + s);
     output.flush();   
     
     System.out.println("User message sent");

where "s" is string.

and Client code stayed like that

                    System.out.println("TEST 1");

            while(true){

                try {

                    line = reader.readLine();

                    System.out.println("TEST 2");

and the problem did not disappeared

Comment: sorry for this mess in the comment but I didn't know how to syle this as Code

Comment: @blackapps do you have discord or something where can we chat

Comment: Please edit your post. No code in comments please.

Comment: @blackapps ok I did

Comment: `+ s);` Well we still dont know what the server sends. And you still did not react on the readLine() comment. And you could have deleted that code comment. Sigh...

Comment: @blackapps I told you that server sends string, and how can I react to your comment, you are true reader.ReadLine does not get any message and that's the problem, why it don't get any message if server sends string message

Comment: We do not know the content of your string s. So we do not know what the server sends. Why so reluctant posting clear code?

Comment: Here is client code https://hastebin.com/ofatabipew.jav. And here is one class of server code https://hastebin.com/jatohoceti.kotlin

Comment: I will not follow your links. Instead you should adapt your posted code so we know what s contains.

Comment: Ok I edited the code

Comment: My god... We still dont know what is send as how would we know what that set contains? Just assign a value to s so all can see what s contains. Its already two hours ago that i asked you to show what you send and we still dont know. Sigh.